# Pointer difference

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I'm studying pointers in Obj-C. Consider following code:

```
char c = 'Q';
char *charPtr;
charPtr = &c;
```

In the second line, we create a pointer variable of type char and name it `charPtr`. In my understanding, that is just pointer to memory address that contain some value of type `char`.

In the third line, we assign `charPtr` value (memory address) to another memory address that contain value `c`.

My question is, what is the difference between `charPtr` and *`charPtr`?

When I wrote `*charPtr = &c` there is an "yellow" warning - `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; remove &`

App crash if launched (`exc_bad_access`)

When I wrote `**charPtr = &c;` compiler warn me with error : `Indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)`

Summary, I want to know difference between `charPtr` and `*charPtr`, and what is `**charPtr` (2 asterisks).

Comment: `charPtr` is a pointer of type `char*`. `*charPtr` is of type `char`;  it's the `char` object that the pointer points to. `**charPtr` is illegal, because `*charPtr` is not a pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson in which case is eligible to use 2 asterisks and what does that mean? Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @Evgeniy Kleban Imagine that you have some abstract pointer declaration T *ptr; T can be any type that is ptr can be a pointer to an object of type T where T is any type. If T in turn is a pointer type as for example char * then you will have char * *ptr.  Now if you want to declare a pointer to object ptr that has type char ** you have to replace in expression T *ptr T with char ** and you will get char ***ptr;

Comment: Please learn the basics of C  before you attempt to learn Objective-C.  You will get a lot of mistaken ideas if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`charPtr` is a variable which holds a pointer to a value of type `char`. After line 2, it holds the address of the variable `c`.

`*charPtr` is an expression which dereferences the pointer and accesses the value at the pointed-to address. Because `charPtr` points to a value of type `char`, the expression `*charPtr` has type `char`. If you read from it, like `char foo = *charPtr;`, you get the `char` at the pointed-to location. In this case, you get the value of `c`, which is `'Q'`. If you write to it, like `*charPtr = 'A';`, you store a new value at the pointed-to location. In this case, you change the contents of `c`.

`**charPtr` is a syntax error because `charPtr` is not a pointer-to-pointer type. The expression has the form of a double dereference: the first dereference is `*charPtr`, just like above. Applying the `*` operator to it again attempts to dereference it again, but the type of `*charPtr` is `char`. It's not a pointer, so it can't be dereferenced.

You might have a variable like this:

```
char **charPtrPtr = &charPtr;
```

Now, `charPtrPtr` is a variable which holds the address of the `charPtr` variable. Its type is `char**`.

`*charPtrPtr` dereferences the pointer it holds and gets the value that it was pointing to. This is the value of `charPtr`, which is, in turn, a pointer to `c`.

`**charPtrPtr` is a double dereference. It's the application of the unary `*` operator to `*charPtrPtr`. Since `*charPtrPtr` is effectively the same as `charPtr`, `**charPtrPtr` is effectively the same as `*charPtr`, which is the same as `c`.

Comment: definitely the best answer, thank you Ken, now all of this clear for me!

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, `*charPtr` refers to the value pointed to by `charPtr`. However, as StackOverflow answers need to be a bit longer than a single sentence I shall try to give you an analogy.

As you are aware, a pointer is sort of like an road sign, saying "the thing you are looking for is at A/B/C whatever". The pointer can be used in several ways.

First and foremost you can point the sign to some other place, which is equivalent to `charPtr = &c`, saying "instead of A/B/C whatever, now use c as the destination".

Second, you can also use the pointer to change whatever it is pointing to, which would be equivalent to `*charPtr = 'Q'`, which doesn't really change the pointer itself, but changes the contents of the field it is pointing to. Keeping with the road sign analogy, it is as if the sign is capable of changing the name of the city (that is the contents of var `c`)

Finally, pointers themselves can also be pointed to, sort of like a sign pointing to the next sign. For example `char **cc = &charPtr` would be a sign pointing to the original sign, in which case `**cc` can be used to access the actual value, while `*cc` is contents of the first sign (the address of the actual value). This can be extended as far as the eye can see, or at least as far as it is practically desirable.

Comment: Thanks Henri, very nice answer and analogy to road signs!

Answer (score 1):

- `char *charPtr;` - you're declaring a variable named charPtr of type `char *`, i.e. "pointer to char"
- `charPtr = &c;` - you are assigning the charPtr variable the address of variable c
- `*charPtr` - in this case the `'*'` character is the indirection operator which means get **the value** in the address pointed by charPtr. The type of *charPtr in this case would be `char` (and **NOT** `char*`)

Now, per the above in the statement `*charPtr = &c` you're trying to assign the address of variable c (`&c`) to a char (`*charPtr`) which is why you get the warning `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; remove &`.

When you're running the application you'll be trying to assign an address (of size 4 or 8 bytes) to a variable of type char (usually 1 or 2 bytes) which is why your application would crash on `exc_bad_access`

Comment: Thank you Amnon for your answer! Especially for error explanation.